# JProfiler 11 Offline Profiling: Timer Trigger for Snapshot not working

Tags: java, jprofiler

I try to offline profile a Java 8 application on a remote host, I'm not allowed to access directly. (A Flink YARN job on a hadoop cluster).

I was able to export relevant JProfiler libraries for offline debugging from within JProfiler for linux 64 via JProfiler -> Session -> Integration Wizards -> New remote integration -> Going some steps and then "Create archive with profiling agent".
I deployed that unextracted archive to /JPROFILER on all hosts with 755 set recursively afterwards for the entire directory structure.

I then created a session on my host with 2 timer triggers. One activates tracking after 2 minutes, the other one stops all tracking after 22 minutes and saves a snapshot. When I run this session in the JProfiler GUI to some arbitrary remote host via SSH I have a connection to, it seems to work fine. In the status bar, I see that after 2 minutes, 3 recordings are running, and after 22 minutes, 0 records are running. But when I try to use that session in offline profiling without GUI, it doesn't work.

For offline profiling on the cluster, I started my YARN application with appropriate options and made sure that the started JVMs would have:

```
-agentpath:/JPROFILER/jprofiler11/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=offline,id=123,config=/JPROFILER/jprofiler_config.xml
```

set. This seems to work fine, from YARN container logs, I see in stderr:

```
JProfiler> Protocol version 63
JProfiler> Java 8 detected.
JProfiler> Offline profiling mode.
JProfiler> 64-bit library
JProfiler> Using config file /JPROFILER/jprofiler_config.xml (id: 123)
JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
JProfiler> Enabling native methods instrumentation.
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Using sampling (2 ms)
JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time
JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
... Some SLF4J stuff, no more JProfiler or other messages ...
```

However, the snapshot file is somehow never saved, maybe none of both triggers is triggered at all (I have no way to check if recording was started or snapshot saving is not working). I tried to find the snapshot in the JVM process working directory, in /tmp and I even searched the entire host via:

```
find / -iname "*flink-taskmanager-snapshot*" 2>/dev/null
```

But I didn't find anything. No further messages were written to stderr, even though my triggers are configured to print something to stderr.

Do you have any idea why triggers/snapshot is not working? JProfiler seems to initialize just fine.
Here is the jprofiler_config.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config version="11.1">
  <sessions>
    <session id="123" name="Flink-TaskManager-JProfiler" type="remote" remoteType="ssh" timeout="5" jvmConfigurationId="100" samplingFrequency="2" recordArrayAlloc="false" compilationMode="manual" compilationTarget="1.8">
      <filters>
        <group type="exclusive" name="Default excludes" template="none">
          <filter type="exclusive" name="$Proxy" />
          <!-- ... stripped ... -->
          <filter type="exclusive" name="workshop." />
        </group>
      </filters>
      <triggers logTarget="stderr" logFile="">
        <timer descriptionType="manual" manualDescription="Start recording" offsetTime="2" intervalTime="2" type="limited">
          <actions>
            <startRecording>
              <cpu enabled="true" />
              <allocation enabled="true" />
              <thread enabled="true" />
              <telemetry enabled="true" />
            </startRecording>
            <startCallTracer />
            <startProbeRecording name="builtin.HttpClientProbe" events="true" />
            <printMessage message="JProfiler: Start tracking" />
          </actions>
        </timer>
        <timer descriptionType="manual" manualDescription="stop recording" offsetTime="22" intervalTime="22" type="limited">
          <actions>
            <stopRecording>
              <cpu enabled="true" />
              <allocation enabled="true" />
              <thread enabled="true" />
              <telemetry enabled="true" />
            </stopRecording>
            <stopCallTracer />
            <stopProbeRecording name="builtin.HttpClientProbe" />
            <saveSnapshot file="flink-taskmanager-snapshot" number="true" />
            <printMessage message="JProfiler: stop recording and save snapshot..." />
          </actions>
        </timer>
      </triggers>
      <probes>
        <probe name="builtin.TrackingInterceptor">
          <id value="1" />
          <id value="2" />
          <id value="5" />
          <id value="7" />
        </probe>
      </probes>
      <ssh port="43490" verifyHosts="false">
        <entry hostName="some-remote-for-tests" userName="yarn" authentication="key" keyFile="C:\Users\theo\.ssh\id_rsa" />
      </ssh>
    </session>
  </sessions>
</config>
```

And here are the outputs about my java version:

```
$ /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/bin/java -XshowSettings:properties -version
Property settings:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    file.encoding = ANSI_X3.4-1968
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = /
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
    java.class.path = .
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/jre/lib/endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/jre/lib/ext
        /usr/java/packages/lib/ext
    java.home = /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/jre
    java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
    java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
        /usr/lib64
        /lib64
        /lib
        /usr/lib
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_181-b13
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_181
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.181-b13
    line.separator = \n
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Linux
    os.version = 3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64
    path.separator = :
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/jre/lib/resources.jar
        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/jre/lib/rt.jar
        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar
        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/jre/lib/jsse.jar
        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/jre/lib/jce.jar
        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/jre/lib/charsets.jar
        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/jre/lib/jfr.jar
        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/jre/classes
    sun.boot.library.path = /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/jre/lib/amd64
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist =
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = ANSI_X3.4-1968
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = unknown
    user.country = US
    user.dir = /var/lib/hadoop-yarn
    user.home = /root
    user.language = en
    user.name = root
    user.timezone =

java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Your config looks good and you should definitely see some output from the triggers. The only thing I can imaging is that the referenced config file does not contain the triggers. Maybe you can experiment with "Session->Conversion Wizards->Convert Application Session to Offline" for the "Adimated Bezier Curve" demo and define a timer trigger that prints a message every 5 seconds.

Comment: What do you mean by the referenced config file does not contain the triggers? I created the config via "Export session settings" and printed the resulting file in it's entirety. The XML looks like it contains the entire trigger definition, no references to somewhere else. If I run "Convert Application Session to Offline", i can't choose my profile as it's a "remote" I guess. If I do it with the animated bezier curve, I only get a .bat file with some JVM args...

Comment: What might be interesting: I test the setup on a dev environment, where I also have root and ssh access to the cluster machines. When I attach the JProfiler UI to the host for remote debugging, I see the JVM in grey, indicating it's instrumented for offline profiling. In total, I see 14 JVMs running for the user I logged into. If I run on the same machine jpenable under that user, I only see 5 JVMs, missing my offline JVM. Might this be related?

Comment: No that sounds normal, jpenable only shows JVMs you can attach to. What I meant is to experiment with a different process to check if you can get triggers working in offline mode and then check what the difference could be.

Comment: Now, to the existing config xml, I added another, very simple third timer right in the trigger element: <timer offsetTimeUnit="s" intervalTime="10" intervalTimeUnit="s"><actions><printMessage message="JProfiler Debug working?" /></actions></timer> . This timer works on all my machines (Windows, Windows WSL linux, remote cluster project). But ONLY this one! THe other two don't work on my local machine as well?!

Comment: Can you try to put print message actions as the first actions in your triggers? Then you can move the print message trigger down until it is not executed anymore so we see when the problem occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tracked it down and it's a bug in JProfiler 11 and 11.1 for offline profiling.

All timers and their actions in offline profiling work well, if they are unlimited, i.e. regularly scheduled. The XML will look like

```xml
<timer offsetTimeUnit="s" intervalTime="10" intervalTimeUnit="s">
  <actions>
    <printMessage message="JProfiler Debug working?" />
  </actions>
</timer>
```

It also works, if I set a limited number of executions !=1 so the config XML will look like this:

```xml
<timer manualDescription="Start recording" offsetTime="30" offsetTimeUnit="s" intervalTime="30" intervalTimeUnit="s" type="limited" count="2">
  <actions>
    <printMessage message="JProfiler: Start tracking" />
  </actions>
</timer>
```

However, if the repetition count is set to 1, the JProfiler config XML won't store the `count` attribute of the `timer` element, probably because it's a default. The offline profiler in that turn won't perform any repetition whereas in contrast the JProfiler UI will execute the trigger 1 time.

To conclude: Manually editing the jprofiler_config.xml and adding `count=1` as attribute to my `timer` solves the problem here. <s>Hopefully, JProfiler will fix the bug soon. I reported the bug on their homepage.</s>

**EDIT** Just 4 hours after reporting the bug on a weekend day, I receivd a bugfix version and as the comment says, JProfiler 11.1.1 will fix this. I keep this post here merely as a short tutorial on how to setup offline profiling (in FLink/YARN) and for people with JProfiler 11.0 as upgrade reminder.

Comment: Thank you for this analysis, this bug will be fixed in 11.1.1, you also contacted us via our support email address and we sent you a build with the fix.